# Confusion in Tab Bar view controller creation

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, sidebar

I'm trying to create an app where both Tab Bar View Controller and Side Bar should appear simultaneously. As of now, i have Tab bar View Controller, and my doubt is i need Side Bar to slide once i click on "more" which is one of the icon in Tab Bar View Controller. Kindly refer to the image attached for the design and help to solve the issue.

Thanks!

**View UI**
[image]

Comment: Add the code that you have already tried to achieve that.